# How to calculate the Jaccard Index (|A∩B|) / (|AUB|) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I am trying following code in Matlab I have two set A and B where as A={1,2,5,6,10} and B={2,3,5,7,9,11}
when I am trying the following code gives an error:

```
A =[1,2,5,6,10]
B =[2,3,5,7,9,11]
C = union( A,B )
D = intersect(A,B)
Result = D/C
```

Here is the error

```
Error using  / 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in code (line 6)
Result = D/C
```

Can anybody help me how to calculate first |A∩B|then |AUB| in Matlab. At the end I will divide the both (|A∩B|) / (|AUB|).

Comment: Do you mean the [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)?

Comment: @RoryDaulton yes I mean the Jaccard Index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the *size* of each set before dividing, which can be done with [`numel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html):

```
Result = numel(D)./numel(C);
```

You can even put it all together into a neat little [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
jaccard = @(A, B) numel(intersect(A, B))./numel(union(A, B));
```

And use it like so:

```
A = [1 2 5 6 10];
B = [2 3 5 7 9 11];
jaccard(A, B)

ans =

   0.222222222222222
```